# Wireless network interface won't come up

Tags: network-interface, systemd-networkd, netplan

The wireless connection of my device (OS Ubuntu 20.04) won't activate.

- This is the state before

  ```
  $ ip a sh dev wlp1s0

   4: wlp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
      link/ether b8:b7:f1:c0:4a:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  ```
- Then I bring it up

  ```
  $ sudo ifconfig wlp1s0 up
  ```
- When I check again, nothing changed ...

  ```
  $ ip a sh dev wlp1s0

   4: wlp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
      link/ether b8:b7:f1:c0:4a:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  ```
- This is the netplan configuration:

  ```
  $ cat /etc/netplan/01-wifi.yaml

   renderer: networkd
   ethernets:
       enp1s0:
           dhcp4: true
       enp2s0:
           dhcp4: true
   version: 2
   wifis:
       wlp1s0:
           optional: true
           access-points:
               "abc":
                   password: "xyz"
           dhcp4: true
  ```
- This is the response from `ifconfig`

  ```
  enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
          inet 10.111.140.246  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.111.140.255
          inet6 fe80::4e38:d5ff:fe11:746e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
          ether 4c:38:d5:11:74:6e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
          RX packets 109968  bytes 126944297 (126.9 MB)
          RX errors 0  dropped 4233  overruns 0  frame 0
          TX packets 61725  bytes 8701147 (8.7 MB)
          TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

  lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
          inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
          inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
          loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
          RX packets 234239  bytes 26630063 (26.6 MB)
          RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
          TX packets 234239  bytes 26630063 (26.6 MB)
          TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

  wlp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
          ether b8:b7:f1:c0:4a:05  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
          RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
          RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
          TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
          TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
  ```

How can I connect the wifi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `ifconfig` clearly shows `wlp1s0` being `up`. If the `sudo ifconfig wlp1s0 up` failed, you would have been notified that this particular interface cannot be raised. `ifconfig [dev] up` by itself is not responsible for establishing connection after raising the particular interface.

1. You need to make sure you have `wpa-supplicant` installed in order to authenticate using WPA2. You can get it through `sudo apt install wpa-supplicant`
2. The file `01-wifi.yaml` is not an effective configuration file. In order for this config to be implemented, you need to execute `sudo netplan generate` for the settings in your `*.yaml` file to be re-generated for the selected renderer, namely `networkd` in your case.
3. Finally, after the configuration gets generated, you need to apply it with `sudo netplan apply`